# Append multiple records from each loop iteration in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursor

I am trying to write a procedure in Oracle PL/SQL that looks like below snippet:

```
    > LOOP:   
         >READ INPUT FROM CURSOR
         >GET OUTPUTS USING SELECT QUERY(OUTPUT RECORD COUNT MAY VARY ON EACH ITERATION)
         >APPEND OUTPUT TO SOME DATA STRUCTURE 
    > END LOOP; 
    >RETURN DATA STRUCTURE
```

Actually I am stuck with this appending task. In each iteration different number of output will be available using a select query. I want to append all of the records in a single data structure.

Suppose inner select query return 3 columns ColA,ColB,ColC and the loop iterates 2 times. Then in 1st iteration it returns:

1,2,3
3,4,5

In the next iteration it returns 4,5,7.

The procedure will return some data structure containing below:

1,2,3
3,4,5
4,5,7

Is there any way?

Comment: What is the returned data type? array, concatenated varchar, etc?

Comment: I am allowed to return anything that holds required set of data. Any composite datatype will do I think.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this can be solved with [pipelined  functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm). 
So it will look something like this:

declare a type

```
 TYPE my_record is RECORD(
       cola      number,
       colb      number,
       colc       number);

TYPE my_table IS TABLE OF my_record;
```

a function

```
function  get_results()  RETURN my_table PIPELINED is 
    my_rec   my_record:=null;
    cursor myCursor(data number) is
    --some select expression
    ;

    begin 

    --loop through outputs 

     FOR item IN myCursor(data)  LOOP
      my_rec:=null; 
      select item.value1,item.value2,item.value2 into rec from dual;
      PIPE ROW(my_rec);
     end loop;
    return;

    end;
```

and finally use it

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_results);
```